# The import org.springframework.kafka cannot be resolved with gradle

Tags: apache-kafka, listener, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I use a 'kafka-clients' dependency and It ran yesterday.
but it is not running because it can't find a KafkaListener Class.
These are a part of source that calls the KafkaListener class and a part of build.gradle file that are relation with KafkaListener.

I try to gradlew clean build before executing the project.

Environment:
OS : Windows
springboot : 2.7.9
spring : 5.3.25
java : 11

KafkaController.java

```
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
...

    @KafkaListener(topics = topicName, groupId = groupId)
    public void listen(String message) {

...

    }
```

build.gradle

```
// kafka
implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.0.0'
```

gradlew clean build on Windows OS

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this dependency

```
implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:3.0.0'
```